# Identify script which yields failing of package build in RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio

If a rebuild of a package,... (click "Install and Restart")

[image]

... fails in RStudio. one gets a log.

```
==> Rcmd.exe INSTALL --no-multiarch --with-keep.source sample

* installing to library 'C:/Users/UserX/Documents/R/win-library/4.0'
* installing *source* package 'sample' ...
** using staged installation
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Warnung: replacing previous import 'glue::collapse' by 'dplyr::collapse' when loading 'sample'
Warnung: replacing previous import 'shiny::dataTableOutput' by 'DT::dataTableOutput' when loading 'sample'
Warnung: replacing previous import 'shiny::renderDataTable' by 'DT::renderDataTable' when loading 'sample'
Error : 'func' is not an exported object from 'namespace:sample'
Fehler: unable to load R code in package 'sample'
```

**Question:**

How can one identify in which script the error was thrown?

**What i tried:**

`devtools::load_all(".")`

`devtools::check(document = FALSE)`

**Expected Output:**

Package builed failed in script `abc.R`.

Comment: The error says you are trying to import or use `sample::func`, but `sample` doesn't export a function named `func`.  The warnings suggest you are importing multiple things with the same name:  `glue::collapse` and `dplyr::collapse`, etc.  This usually happens if you import all of the exports from each package.  It's better to list the specific imports that you plan to use, i.e. `importFrom(glue, collapse)` instead of `import(glue)`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The error i am mosten often Aware of. I just would be interested to know which of the scripts causes the error, do you have any idea how to do that?

Comment: I'd guess it's your NAMESPACE file rather than R code, but it might be R code.  To find that just do a global search for `sample::func`.

Comment: thanks again. A global search is a good step. I am not after solving that specific Problem, but in General understand all build Fails and the way i would like to do so would be the expected Output. So if it would be `NAMESPACE` then expected Output would Name that specific file automatically if that is possible.

Comment: If you want that, I think you'll have to modify the sources.  That message comes from here:  https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/254ec9baf621de55181900067a7c89e2baa5b90a/src/main/envir.c#L3911-L3914, and it doesn't keep a record of what file it was looking at when it happened.